# I cannot import tensorflow even though it is installed. (VSCODE)

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, command-line

Before you say it: YES!! I have checked the twelve different articles with solutions. **None of them worked.** Mostly because they were outdated.

I can run tensorflow in command prompt with python just fine, but in vs code it just doesnt work.

[image]

This is really annoying.

I tried to install older versions and that did not work either. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow, which didnt work.

EDIT:

VS CODE SYSTEM PATH: [image]

COMMAND LINE PATHS: [image]

Comment: You must have vs code configured to use a different version of Python than the command line is using.

Comment: Run this code in both environments and show us: `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: That's the problem.  You're using plain python in one environment, and Anaconda in the other.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Tensorflow version available to be compatible with the existing installed python 3.11 in your environment. Please check this tested [build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) for the same.

Please retry by downgrading the `python version to <= 3.10` and let us know if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Check your desired version of tensorflow, then check the compatible Python build.
Afterwards, open an anaconda prompt and create a new environement with the desired python version and packages :

```
conda create --name ENVNAME python=3.X "PKG1>7.6" PKG2=3.2
```

Activate the conda env :

```
conda activate ENVNAME
```

**IMPORTANT** Open VScode using :

```
code .
```

Otherwise you will be using your native python installation.

Select your desired interpreter by opening the command Palette Ctrl+Shift+P and typing :

```
Python: Select Interpreter
```

A list of all the interpreter will appear select the one with the name of your environement.